# Laravel 8 Class Based Model Factories

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to figure out why when I try and create a factory of my Player class and `dd($this)` it comes back as that its not overriding the state of the model. What also doesn't make sense is that it is a collection of two items for the states.

Can anyone give further clarification for any of this?

```
$player = Player::factory()->injured()->create();


<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Enums\PlayerStatus;
use App\Models\Player;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class PlayerFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected string $modelClass = Player::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name,
            'height' => $this->faker->numberBetween(60, 95),
            'weight' => $this->faker->numberBetween(180, 500),
            'hometown' => $this->faker->city.', '.$this->faker->state,
            'status' => PlayerStatus::__default,
        ];
    }

    public function injured(): self
    {
        $this->state([
            'status' => PlayerStatus::INJURED,
        ]);

        dd($this);

        $now = now();
        $start = $now->copy()->subDays(2);

        $this->hasEmployments(1, ['started_at' => $start]);

        $this->hasInjuries(1, ['started_at' => $now]);

        return $this;
    }
}


    ^ Database\Factories\PlayerFactory^ {#2650
  #modelClass: "App\Models\Player"
  #model: null
  #count: null
  #states: Illuminate\Support\Collection^ {#2647
    #items: array:2 [
      0 => Closure()^ {#2631
        class: "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory"
        this: Database\Factories\PlayerFactory {#2626 …}
        use: {
          $state: []
        }
      }
      1 => Closure()^ {#2646
        class: "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory"
        this: Database\Factories\PlayerFactory {#2648 …}
        use: {
          $state: []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  #has: Illuminate\Support\Collection^ {#2610
    #items: []
  }
  #for: Illuminate\Support\Collection^ {#2640
    #items: []
  }
  #afterMaking: Illuminate\Support\Collection^ {#2455
    #items: []
  }
  #afterCreating: Illuminate\Support\Collection^ {#2453
    #items: []
  }
  #connection: null
  #faker: null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method call:

```
$this->state([
        'status' => PlayerStatus::INJURED,
]);
```

does not modify the current object - it creates a new Factory Instance with the updated 'status'. And this new Factory should be returned by the injured method.

In this case one solution would be:

```
public function injured(): self
{
    $injuredPlayer = $this->state([
        'status' => PlayerStatus::INJURED,
    ]);

    $now = now();
    $start = $now->copy()->subDays(2);

    $injuredPlayer->hasEmployments(1, ['started_at' => $start]);

    $injuredPlayer->hasInjuries(1, ['started_at' => $now]);

    return $injuredPlayer;
}
```